# Point defects in solid affect energy bands

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When we want to draw the band diagram of a solid and we know the solid has point defects can we leave some 'columns' of the band diagram empty?

Comment: AFAIK, all crystalline solids have point defects in the form of vacancies. And their concentration is a function of temperature.

Comment: Point defects are localized states, not extended states. While their energy levels may be represented over a band structure they are not actually part of the band structure.